# In app purchase in multiple regions

Tags: iphone, sdk, in-app-purchase

I have an app on the appstore, the app can be sold on all appstores (us, ca, es, fr etc...)

the app is not localized to any other languages then english.

now i want to add in-app purchase option, but when i try to make a purchase on other region (with a non us store test account) it doesn't let me make the purchase...

in apple's In App Purchase Programming Guide there is this line:

"You should make at least one test account for each region that your application is localized for"

when i upload the app i could pick the region i want the to be sold regardless the language localization and the app is localized only for english language... what do they mean???

do they mean the localization in itunes connect? but i didn't localized anything there and still able to sell the app in all regions...

i didn't had an option to choose region when i added new in-app item.

please help me understand this... thanks!